# Add to value with time (Excel)

Tags: excel, time

I would like to know if it's possible to add value using time?

For example, I want to add 100 to a cell every minute that has that has passed which would cause the value of the cell to increase by 6,000 by the end of the hour.

Comment: Do you want this to update every minute or would you be ok with having in a formula to calculate the minutes that have passed when it's looked at?

Comment: I would prefer that the cell updates every minute but I'm not sure if that's possible?

Comment: You can use VBA and `Application.OnTime`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run **StartTimer** to start the incrementation and **StopTimer** to stop the incrementation.  The cell in question is **B9** :

```
Public RunWhen As Double
Public Const cRunIntervalSeconds = 60
Public Const cRunWhat = "refresh"

Sub StartTimer()
RunWhen = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, cRunIntervalSeconds)
Application.OnTime earliesttime:=RunWhen, procedure:=cRunWhat, _
     schedule:=True
End Sub

Sub StopTimer()
   On Error Resume Next
   Application.OnTime earliesttime:=RunWhen, _
       procedure:=cRunWhat, schedule:=False
End Sub

Sub refresh()
    Range("B9").Value = Range("B9").Value + 100
    Call StartTimer
End Sub
```